# Append two pandas dataframe with different shapes and in for loop using python or pandasql

Tags: sql, pandas

I have two dataframe such as:

df1:

```
     id  A  B  C  D

     1   a  b  c  d
     1   e  f  g  h
     1   i  j  k  l
```

df2:

```
     id  A  C  D

     2   x  y  z
     2   u  v  w
```

The final outcome should be:

```
    id  A   B  C  D

    1   a  b  c  d
    1   e  f  g  h
    1   i  j  k  l
    2   x     y  z
    2   u     v  w
```

These tables are generated using for loop from json files. So have to keep on appending these tables one below another.

`Note`: Two dataframes 'id' column is always different.

My approach:

data is a dataframe in which column 'X' has json data and has and "id" column also.

```
          df1=pd.DataFrame()
          for i, row1 in data.head(2).iterrows():

             df2= pd.io.json.json_normalize(row1["X"])
             df2.columns = df2.columns.map(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])
             df2["id"]=[row1["id"] for i in range(df2.shape[0])]



             if len(df1)==0:
                df1=df2.copy()

             df1=pd.concat((df1,df2), ignore_index=True)


      Error: AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items # manager items: 46, # tot_items: 49
```

How to solve this using python or pandas sql.

Comment: in pandas use : pd.concat([df1,df2]). In sql, i believe union should do the trick : select * from table 1 union select from table 2;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat) to concatenate two dataframes like

```
>>> pd.concat((df,df1), ignore_index=True)
   id  A    B  C  D
0   1  a    b  c  d
1   1  e    f  g  h
2   1  i    j  k  l
3   2  x  NaN  y  z
4   2  u  NaN  v  w
```

Comment: I am getting this error: AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items
# manager items: 46, # tot_items: 49